# How to return JWT token after user created in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am using Model Serializer and I want to return JWT Token after the user is created. Is there any way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """Serializers for User objects"""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True,
                                   'min_length': 5,
                                   'style': {
                                       'input_type': 'password'
                                   }}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypter password"""
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0 - for authentication
and for serializing model using rest_framework.serializers 's ModelSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved what I wanted using the code below. Thanks to @aman kumar.
I am posting my own answer which refers for full working option that returns user email and the token.

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """Serilizers for User objects"""
    token = SerializerMethodField('get_auth_token')

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'token')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True,
                                     'min_length': 5,
                                     'style': {
                                         'input_type': 'password'
                                     }}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypter password"""
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

    def get_auth_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Update a user setting the password correctly"""
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        user = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
"""Serializers for User objects"""

    jwt_token = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_jwt_token')
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password','jwt_token')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True,
                               'min_length': 5,
                               'style': {
                                   'input_type': 'password'
                               }}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypter password"""
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user

    def get_jwt_token(self,user):
        """ create jwt token """
        data = dict()
        token_class = RefreshToken
        refresh = token_class.for_user(user)

        data['refresh'] = str(refresh
        data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)
        return data
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """Serializers for User objects"""
   auth_token = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'auth_token')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True,
                                   'min_length': 5,
                                   'style': {
                                       'input_type': 'password'
                                   }}}
    def get_auth_token(self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
        payload = jwt_payload_handler(self)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypter password"""
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

Comment: I know your method works but I have a still question how can I return the token with user?

Comment: from that you need to overide the save method pf serializer, create method exception only object instance. but finally in response you would be sending in a dict

Comment: Thanks I have achieved it using Serializeremethod field. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings

jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER
jwt_decode_handler = api_settings.JWT_DECODE_HANDLER
jwt_get_username_from_payload = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER


class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """Serializers for User objects"""

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True,
                                   'min_length': 5,
                                   'style': {
                                       'input_type': 'password'
                                   }}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new user with encrypter password"""
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

**UPDATED:**

```
class YourViewClass:
    ...
    instance = serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
    payload = jwt_payload_handler(instance)
    return Response({"user": instance, "token": jwt_encode_handler(payload)})
```

Comment: The method **`create()`** should return **`Meta.model`** instance (ie, the ***`User`*** model instance). This will definitely raise exception.

Comment: tuple' object has no attribute 'email'

Comment: Should I use different serializer?